# How can i fix primefaces checkboxMenu on IE 8?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple checkboxmenu that works great on Chrome but totally messed up on Internet Explorer 8 + I can't give up IE8 it's a customer requirement.

Comment: /*fix checkboxmenu on IE8 Worked for me Thanks Anyways*/
                .ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box{
                    display: block;
                }

Comment: Please remove your comment and create an answer from it and accept it. This way you stick to the 'way-it-should be'.